# Commit history not showing on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

One project of mine stopped showing history or reacting to push events in any way after upgrading to `gitlab` version `8.3.2` (but it could also be on previous versions as we update frequently).

I'm using a plain gitlab docker installation. Is there a way to let gitlab reload the commit history ?

#### UPDATE:

This is happening on serval projects not just one, but until now there's no common factor between them apart from having recently enabled CI and being imported from an external git repository.

Comment: are you sure you don't mess with push and commit?

Comment: git is working perfectly. we can pull, push, and everything. It is only the web interface that's not showing commit history. It shows branches though. If I trigger a build it will do it. so everything is normal except for the web interface not showing the commits hitstory and not reacting to push triggering builds.

Comment: Sure that it is not issues of web browser cache (can be force reloaded page with Shift button pressed), or may be proxy server cached?

Comment: 100% sure it is not a browser issue. tryied different browsers on different computer. cleaned cache, etc. Also that would not explain why builds are not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it!

The cause of this behavior was that the git repository was imported with the wrong directory structure.

It was:

```
repository.git/
 |
 +-> .git/<bare-repo-content>
```

Instead of just:

```
repository.git/<bare-repo-content>
```

The fix was to simply rename and move the bare repo:

```
mv repository.git/.git tmp.git
rm -rf repository.git
mv tmp.git repository.git
```